# Scrapy - using URI parameters for logging file

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to use Scrapy's built-in URI parameters to name my log file (as I can name the feed export), but this does not work. Could someone explain the difference?

This can be reproduced by starting a new project, creating a generic spider, updating the settings file with the below parameters, and running the spider.

```
scrapy startproject project_name
cd project_name
scrapy genspider project_spider
# add above settings to settings.py
scrapy crawl project_spider
#outputs items file with correct name but log file has incorrect name
```

My settings file contains the following:

```
FEED_URI = '%(name)s--%(time)s.csv'
LOG_FILE = '%(name)s--%(time)s.log'
```

Comment: could you explain some more?

Comment: hi, added some more detail. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have separate project (BOT_NAME) for each spider then below can be used (generally in this case spider name is same as BOT_NAME), You can format the time as per your need.

```
import time

BOT_NAME = "test"
FEED_URI = '%(name)s--%(time)s.csv'
LOG_FILE = "%s--%s.log" % (BOT_NAME, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S'))
```

But if you are having multiple spiders in single project (BOT_NAME) then you may have to use logging and define the **LOG_FILE** at each spider level ( in __init __ ) as one example given below, it should generate the log with spider_name as per your need.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CSVFeedSpider
from scrapy import log
import time

class TestSpider(CSVFeedSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['testwebsite.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.testwebsite.com']

    # check below how logging is set
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
    LOG_FILE = "%s--%s.log" % (self.name, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S'))
    log.log.defaultObserver = log.log.DefaultObserver()
    log.log.defaultObserver.start()
    log.started = False
    log.start(LOG_FILE)
    super(TestSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    # headers = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'image_link']
    # delimiter = '\t'

    def parse_row(self, response, row):
    ...
```